# How to get jest coverage only for new code?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jestjs, code-coverage, ts-jest

I ran jest with `--onlyChanged` and tried to get coverage rate only for my new code. However the coverage report still showed me the analysis of entire files.

See the example below:

```
function oldFn(){
  ....
}

// new code
function newFn(){
  ....
}
```

Assume test file of above example covers only `newFn`, not `oldFn`.

I want to know if there a way to get 100% coverage rate since all new code is covered.

I am running `jest@29.6.4` on MacOS 13.5.1.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a simple command that gives you exactly what you want, but there are some things that might be close:

- You can run `jest --coverage` to get coverage per file. and also which lines are uncovered.
- Sonarcloud gives you the coverage on new code. That sounds like what you want to know. So you could use that.
- In Intellij you can use 'run with coverage' (the green arrow with the little shield) to see exactly which lines are covered and which are not, which is really helpful.